# User Local Time in Wordpress Comment Timestamp

Tags: javascript, wordpress, date, timezone

I'm trying to get Wordpress comments to show the time, based on the visitors's location. So when a visitor posts a comment, it is according to their time.

Since it can't be done solely with PHP, I've utilized Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
    document.write("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>")
</script>
```

Of course, this only posts the current time. If I implement it into my comments inside get_the_time (code below), all the timestamps will read the same time- the visitor's current time.

PHP:

```
<div class="comment-time-stamp"><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_the_time()) ?></div></div>
```

So I tried to add a function that will only affect the visitor's post:

```
function local_date_time($format, $timestamp) {
    $timezone_str = get_option('timezone_string') ?: 'UTC';
    $timezone = new \DateTimeZone($timezone_str);

    // The date in the local timezone.
    $date = new \DateTime(null, $timezone);
    $date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    $date_str = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // Pretend the local date is UTC to get the timestamp
    // to pass to local_date_time().
    $utc_timezone = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
    $utc_date = new \DateTime($date_str, $utc_timezone);
    $timestamp = $utc_date->getTimestamp();

    return $format, $timestamp, true;
}
```

It broke the page and stopped it from loading. I am a little lost on where to go from here.

Comment: in your first script, just replace `new Date()` with `new Date(thePhpProvidedDateStamp)`

Comment: If I use the first code and add `thePhpProvidedDateStamp`, doesn't it give every comment posted (new and old) the current date? As opposed to something like `get_comment_date`.

Comment: Okay, not exactly an answer, but this seems to work so far! There is a Wordpress plugin that automatically adjusts the site dates and time based on location: (https://wordpress.org/plugins/localtime/installation/)

Comment: im just saying you can feed the comment date to javascript via new Date(), and the code will work like you describe, but with the comment date instead of the current date.

Comment: I must have implemented your suggestion incorrectly. If I used the suggested javascript _outside_ of `get_comment_date()`, the times would repeat for all posts. If i used it _inside_, it incorrectly generated all potential times:
`get_comment_date('<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentDate = new Date(thePhpProvidedDateStamp)
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
    document.write("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>")
</script>')`